# Доступ к локальным переменным из анонимного класса Java

Tags: java

Всем добрый день, стало интересно, как работает доступ к локальным переменным из анонимного класса. Допустим у меня такой код

```
public void addListener() {
String s = "Hello World";
this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
});
}
```

И пусть этот метод будет определён в классе унаследованном от JButton. Вот мы при нажатии на эту кнопку
всегда будет видеть сообщение Hello World! Но мне интересно, как он будет ссылаться на этот Hello World!. Есть предположение, что у него есть некая невидимая ссылка на тот же на объект, что ссылается s т.е. на Hello World!, но я
не уверен в своём предположении, так что прошу у вас ответа на данный вопрос, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто, анонимные классы компилируются в отдельные классы с названием `<название родительского класса>$<индекс>.class`. Если посмотреть на его содержимое, в частности, для примера который был в вопросе, то увидим следующее:

```
class ru.izebit.Main$1 implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {
  final java.lang.String val$s;
  final ru.izebit.Main this$0;
  ru.izebit.Main$1(ru.izebit.Main, java.lang.String);
  public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent);
}
```

`ru.izebit.Main` - это название класса, в котором я объявил анонимный класс.
`val$s` - ссылка на строковую переменную со значением `"Hello World"`
`this$0` - ссылка на объект класса, в котором был объявлен анонимный класс, т.к. из анонимного класса есть возможность получать доступ к полям объекта, а это происходит именно через эту переменную

Comment: Ага, видимо поэтому мы и должны объявлять используемые локальные переменные как final, т.к. если мы изменим их, то она будет отличаться  от значения переменной в анонимном классе и логика нашего алгоритма будет изменена

Comment: @ProstoCoder именно так

Comment: Премного благодарю

Comment: если есть ссылка на объект, то нет разницы какое значение там хранится

Comment: @RomanC если вы объявили переменную в методе, и потом ее передали в анонимный класс, то через ссылку на объект вы ее не получите никак, от слова совсем.

Comment: если есть ссылка на объект то я получу все, без слов.

Comment: ок, https://gist.github.com/izebit/10ca1ef135d1fed4593dca2d40ef817b достаньте мне через объект main переменную param

Comment: объект main не имеет ссылки на переменную param.

Answer (score 0):

Можно привести аналогию с внутренним классом. 
Из внутреннего класса у нас есть доступ ко всем, в том числе приватным переменным обрамляющего, в этом плане его можно представить как метод, объявленный в этом классе.
В случае с локальным классом, или с его частным случаем анонимным, метод можно соотнести с вешнем классом, а анонимный класс с внутренним.

Comment: Но на вопрос мой вы не ответили, всё таки не стоит сравнивать анонимный класс с методом в методе который типа класс. Метод в отличие от класса не может хранить переменные, а у меня вопрос как раз по тому, как анонимный класс получает доступ к локальным переменным и как он их хранит.

Comment: В том и дело, что он их не хранить, а просто имеет к ним доступ, как, например, класс, реализующий интерфейс, имеет доступ к константам этого интерфейса или метод имеет доступ к полям класса.